# Creating a list of named ranges for every sheet

Tags: excel, named-ranges

There are many things similar but not exactly my issue.  I'm trying to name ranges off of each tab based upon details of the tab name.  I have placed the tab names in one sheet and now want to define named ranges based upon these cells.  I can't get it to like my range names with a variable.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As String
    Dim YY As String
    Dim z As String
    Dim ZZ As String

    For x = 1 To Worksheets.Count

    Sheets("List of Tab Names").Activate

    y = Cells(x, 1).Value
    z = Cells(x, 2).Value
    YY = y & "Data2"
    ZZ = z & "YoA2"


    Sheets(y).Activate

    Range("C9:BG233").Name = " ' " & YY & " ' "
    Range("C7:BG7").Name = " ' " & ZZ & " ' "

    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the single quotes around the range names. Just try:

```
Range("C9:BG233").Name = YY
Range("C7:BG7").Name = ZZ
```

Comment: I get a run-time error '1004': message.  It says I'm trying to name something with a non letter or an underscore.  So, I'm changing the name of the column to see if that help.

Comment: What values do you have for y and z? I'm assuming y is exactly what to your sheet names, but if they have any spaces or hyphens it will cause issues.

Comment: ah!!   There are spaces in the names of the tabs.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your idea right i think all you are missing is the function `Worksheets(sheetname)`

As you can see in the code here:

```
Range("A1:A5").Name = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Comment: My problem is I want to loop through all the the sheets and name them.  I need to turn Sheet2 into a  loop.

Comment: the function `Worksheets()` can be used with an integer (like `Worksheets(1)`) so you can do a for loop to go over all the sheets.     Or do you just want to give name for the sheets?